# Can't get Mongo Shell working on Windows 7

Tags: windows, mongodb

I'm working on a Windows 7 SP1 machine.

I just started using Atlas. Trying to connect to my cluster, I followed the instructions to download mongo shell. I put it in a folder, and opened a terminal. In the terminal I navigated to the bin directory of the mongo shell download folder. Then, when I try to run the connection string, I get an error that I'll translate from spanish:

"Cannot find procedure's point of entry BCryptHash in bcrypt.dll."

I don't know which other details to include in my question. How do I fix this so I can connect via mongo shell?

Comment: Why do you run an 17 years old unsupported operating system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Windows](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

> **Platform Support**
>
> EOL Notice
>
> ```
> MongoDB 4.4 Community Edition removes support for Windows 8.1 / Server 2012 R2
> MongoDB 4.4 Community Edition removes support for Windows 8 / Server 2012
> MongoDB 4.4 Community Edition removes support for Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2
> ```
>
> MongoDB 4.4 Community Edition supports the following 64-bit versions
> of Windows on x86_64 architecture:
>
> ```
> Windows Server 2019
> Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016
> ```
>
> MongoDB only supports the 64-bit versions of these platforms.

Quite clear I would say.

Comment: Well, crud. I guess I'm off to research how to install an earlier version or something. Thank you for the help.